# Css grid height is overflowing

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've got 2 columns with CSS grid (in TailwindCss). The problem is that the height of the second column is overriding its parent (see dotted line):

https://play.tailwindcss.com/eNhVFPmU4Z

It should have the same height has the parent component.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Put a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: What about removing the `h-full` class from line 80?

Comment: @Boguz yes but it needs to be the full width of the parent component.

Comment: @Jenssen `h-full` doesnt seem to be for full width. I think tailwaind has other classes for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check: https://play.tailwindcss.com/pbEsTV05NP. I added `flex` and `flex-col` to parent of that box which was overflowing.